# Shorten Controller method in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am writing an ASP.NET Core MVC application where users should be able to upload an Excel file, when a file gets uploaded I need to read the uploaded file an create a Model of the data inside the file.

I am currently creating this model in my Controller method but this made my method quite long.

My current solution is creating a class inside my Controller which deals with creating a model from an Excel file but I feel like this is the wrong way to do it.

So my question is: What is the right place to put the code that reads my excel file and puts it inside a model?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new .NET Standard library and create there the class that builds the model.

The recommended way is to use the class as an implementation and an interface (IExcelModelBuilder) that exposes all the public methods of that class (ExcelModelBuilder). This way you can inject this service into your controller constructor and, as a bonus, you can easily unit test it too.

You can read more about [Dependency Injection in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection).

You can register the service in your startup file:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  {...}
  services.AddTransient<IExcelModelBuilder, ExcelModelBuilder>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:Create a new .NET Standard library (Services)

Step 2:Add the reference into the mvc application of that library.

Step 3:Step two create a class that will be dealing with all the stuff like that if you have a limited number of tasks to perform ,
but if you want to separate it and wants a generic solution then Create an Interface (IUpload) and then implement all its methods in a class (Upload).also register the service in your startup file: